# Web change hash (#) for slash (/) on url

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, web

I'm making an "*One-page navigation web*" and I want to know if there's possible to replace hash character from an url to slash character.
For example, I have this:
***www.example.com/#aboutus***
and I want to change for this:
***www.example.com/aboutus***

But staying in same place, just changing the position to anchor link.

I need to change .htaccess, or wich javascript (and derived) function is recommended.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: don't forget that you'll need to handle inverse situation – when user goes to www.example.com/aboutus, but should reach www.example.com/#aboutus

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean SPA (Single-Page Application), you can take advantage of the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to change the URL without actually changing pages.

```
window.history.pushState(stateObj, "About Us", "aboutus")
```

And, although I think it's supported by all major browsers, you still may want to keep the hash approach in mind for fallback should the API be absent (yes, I'm [looking at you](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate) IE).

Additional reference:

- http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: You also need to set up server side code to return the right response when `/aboutus` is requested.